# Python: Object to list of tuples extraction

Tags: python, django

I have an object in the following format:

```
{
  'af': {
    'bidi': False, 
    'code': 'af', 
    'name': 'Afrikaans', 
    'name_local': 'Afrikaans'
  },
  'ar': {
    'bidi': True, 
    'code': 'ar', 
    'name': 'Arabic', 
    'name_local': 'العربيّة'
  },
  ...
}
```

This is a list of locales as found in `django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO`. (see here for full reference: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/__init__.py)).

Now, I am hoping to utilise this list in a model class:

```
locale = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=get_locale_choices(), default='en')
```

Such that I have the following utility function:

```
from django.conf.locale import LANG_INFO

def get_locale_choices():
    return ?
```

Now, that `?` that gets returned, I'd like to be in the following format:

```
[
    ('af', 'Afrikaans'),
    ('ar', 'Arabic'),
    ...
]
```

My question is this, how would I turn the `LANG_INFO` dictionary into the above list of tuples?

It feels like something like this is close:

```
a_dict = {'color': 'blue', 'fruit': 'apple', 'pet': 'dog'}
d_items = a_dict.items()
d_items  # Here d_items is a view of items
dict_items([('color', 'blue'), ('fruit', 'apple'), ('pet', 'dog')])
```

But...hmmm, not sure? I want to extract a sub-value from the key item...

Comment: `[(k, v['name']) for k, v in the_object.items()]`…?

Comment: To be fussy, would `[(v['code'], v['name']) for k, v in the_object.items()]` work? I will check! Thanks @deceze

Comment: in this case, simply `[(v['code'], v['name']) for v in the_object.values()]`. But I prefer @deceze solution

Comment: @buran Thanks Buran, appreciate that - one issue I have seen tho is that sometimes the key `'code'` or `'name'` doesn't always exist in `v` ...

Comment: as I comment in response to same question in the answers - use `dict.get()` method

Comment: Apologies Buran, I saw that after I commented. Thank you, it looks like it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
from django.conf.locale import LANG_INFO

def get_locale_choices():
    return [(k, v['name']) for k, v in LANG_INFO.items() if 'name' in v]
```

The `... if 'name' in v` part is necessary to ensure that the cases that have a `'fallback'` but no `'name'` (e.g. `zh-cn`, `zh-my`, `zh-sg`, etc.) are ignored.

Result:

```
[('af', 'Afrikaans'), ('ar', 'Arabic'), ...]
```

Note: `django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO` seems to be internal to Django, so your use of it isn't officially sanctioned by Django.

Comment: Ahhh @Flux - I feel like this would work - but is there a catch I can add for the following issue - when 'name' doesn't exist .... I think looking at `LANG_INFO`at the bottom, there appears to be some weird `'zh-sg': {'fallback': ['zh-hans'],}`. Also, I think it should be robust because I am using this in a `Django` project...

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos What's the expected behavior when you encounter Singaporean Mandarin (`zh-sg`)? Ignore it? (Note: ignoring it is my recommendation because it is already covered by the fallbacks).

Comment: use `dict.get()` method